# Login for Google Profiles account doesn't work after joining Google+

Tags: support, openid, login, google-openid

After joining Google+, the `profiles.google.com/username` URL redirects to `plus.google.com/[long number]/posts`. When trying to log in on SO using the `profiles.google.com` URL, I got (line breaks for clarity):

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match.

Assertion endpoint info: 
ClaimedIdentifier: https://profiles.google.com/username 
ProviderLocalIdentifier: https://profiles.google.com/username 
ProviderEndpoint: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=profiles 
OpenID version: 2.0 
Service Type URIs: 
Discovered endpoint info: 
[{ 
ClaimedIdentifier: https://plus.google.com/longnumber 
ProviderLocalIdentifier: https://plus.google.com/longnumber 
ProviderEndpoint: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=profiles 
OpenID version: 2.0 
Service Type URIs: 
  http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon 
  http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0 
  http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup
  http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon 
  http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0 
},]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you simply click on the google button?

Comment: @Kobi: Hm. Well, that did work but I have both my google account openid and my google profile openid associated with my SE accounts. Last I knew those were separate, so if I hadn't also had the account openid associated it wouldn't have worked. I seem to recall the main google openid provider being undesirable for some reason a while back, so I'd been using the profile version since then. Maybe that isn't the case anymore.

Comment: same thing happening to me. used my alternate login and removed my google profiles and added myopenid back.

Comment: You also must have your profile Public for it to work anymore.

Comment: There is also something different I got: When I typed my Google+ URL, I was redirected to my Google Profile URL. Because of that, I can't get in to Google+. Really, this is confusing.

Comment: I hope they change this, google seems to completely miss the point of OpenIDs and how they're *actually* used in the real world.  A provider repeatedly breaking endpoints isn't a provider, they're actively doing more harm than good.

Comment: So what do those of us that now have google+ do?

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I'm just using the normal Google (non-profile) OpenID now. Not sure what you should do if you're using the profile as your main login and don't have an alternate.

Comment: Can any of you Google plus users send me an invite?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears that signing up for Google+ breaks Google Profile OpenIDs.

There's not much we can do from our end, as there's no obvious connection between the old and new identifiers.

If you intend to signup for Google+, you should use a different OpenID provider than Google Profiles.  If you're already locked out, create a new account using the top-level Google login; it should be auto-merged with your existing Google Profile backed account, giving you an alternate OpenID to login with (after which, you should delete the Google Profile OpenID).

If you're still having issues, e-mail us using the `contact` link with the details; preferably from the Gmail account associated with your Google Profile.

Answer (score 8):

I *think* existing users can log-in using the standard Google. If it wasn't their alternate, and they are asked to "create a new account" they can hit cancel, but since they are now authenticated with Google, it still works, so it will detect that they are logged in. That happened on a few sites where my only login was my Google profile's login.

Comment: This has worked for me, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

in Api Console replace your redirect urls to http and remove https and You can also use 'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' . This solution worked for me.