# Google Plus has broken Google Profile OpenID logon to StackOverflow

Tags: bug, openid, google, google-openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login for Google Profiles account doesn't work after joining Google+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96982/login-for-google-profiles-account-doesnt-work-after-joining-google)

There's a really, really nasty bug with Google+: if you were using your Google Profile (e.g. http://google.com/profiles/skolima ) as an OpenID - say, on StackOverflow - you will no longer be able to log in! Google messed up badly, and when you enable Google+, you profile no longer provides your old OpenID - instead, it tries to log you on with your Google+ profile. Which works fine, except it's a totally different account! WTF?