# Logging in with personal OpenID delegated to Google Profiles, "This login is new to Stack Overflow"

Tags: support, bug, openid, google-openid

I am a [registered user of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099571/jim-delahunt), and I have an OpenID from my personal domain, http://id.jdlh.com/jdlh/ associated with the account.  At my domain, I delegated OpenID provision to Google. My understanding, though, is that this delegation should be invisible to StackOverflow. They see only my own OpenID.

When I attempt to log in to Stack Overflow, and supply this OpenID, I get an expected page from Google asking me to log in.  Then I get the following message from StackOverflow:

> **Confirm**
>
> This login is new to Stack Overflow:
>
> profiles.google.com/115288663061471092982
>
> [Confirm and create new account] [Cancel]

Neither of these is what I want to do.

How can I persuade Stack Overflow to let me log in with my personal OpenID?  I don't want to create a new account with a different OpenID, and then have to merge the two.

Did I supply the wrong OpenID?  No, actually; when I do account recovery, using the email address registered with my StackOverflow account, I get a recovery message which repeats the same OpenID which I used in the first place.

I checked for duplicates of this question. Some seemed similar, but aren't duplicates:

- [Stack Overflow login with OpenID goes to new account rather than existing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98867/stack-overflow-login-with-openid-goes-to-new-account-rather-than-existing) appears to boil down to questioners using different OpenID URLs, but my account recovery email appears to confirm I'm using the same OpenID URL.
- [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) is treated as a duplicate of similar questions, but it's about cleaning up the duplicate accounts which result from a problem like this, not about making Stack Overflow let me in to my account in the first place.

For what it's worth, here's the URL of the **Confirm** page. I added line breaks for legibility. The URL has a lot of query parameters which seem to indicate that my personal OpenID URL is being acknowledged. But I don't understand all those parameters very deeply:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/
?s=5a04403f-c900-4906-a578-cde63ec7c1fd
&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=id.jdlh.com%2Fjdlh
&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
&openid.mode=id_res
&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud%3Fsource%3Dprofiles
&openid.response_nonce=2012-06-17T05%3A19%3A59ZYQByCd-ZO0rKtg
&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3D5a04403f-c900-4906-a578-cde63ec7c1fd%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Did.jdlh.com%252Fjdlh
&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9VEes_mnw0NMUCw-N_a_itybQzvTguFN6rATlRNKe1WSp_k-E8c
&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias4%2Cext1.value.alias4
&openid.sig=5agXuKTS80rgC6Z47BIJkHjFBo8%3D
&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fprofiles.google.com%2F115288663061471092982
&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fprofiles.google.com%2F115288663061471092982
&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0
&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response
&openid.ext1.type.alias4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail
&openid.ext1.value.alias4=jim.deleteme.delahunt%40gmail.com
```

Comment: Confirmed; no idea when this broke though, as I haven't tried delegating to Google for this in a while. Might be related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96982/login-for-google-profiles-account-doesnt-work-after-joining-google

Comment: Could not reproduce with an OpenID delegated to LiveJournal; I logged out on SO and logged in, and the “my logins” popup showed that I had logged in with my personal domain rather than LJ.

Answer (score 5):

I am [user188413](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/188413/user188413), now logged in as myself, having worked around the problem.

I decided that Google didn't want to provide OpenID services properly to delegators like myself. In part I reached this conclusion from not finding any documentation where Google says it does want to provide OpenID services to delegators. In part it was based on a Stack Overflow reply where someone claims Yahoo doesn't provide OpenID services properly to delegators. If Yahoo! doesn't want to play, maybe Google doesn't either.

I created an account on the [Stack Exchange OpenID provider](https://openid.stackexchange.com/). Then I commented out the  entries in my HTML Head section which delegated to Google, and inserted the  entries which delegate to https://openid.stackexchange.com/.  Voila! I could log in to Stack Overflow with my own OpenID again.

I read some posts saying that the format of Google Local ID URLs changed with the advent of Google+. The old URLs used the domain name `profiles.google.com`, the post-Google+ URLs use `plus.google.com`.  Simply changing the `local_id` link from old to new Google URL didn't fix this problem for me, though.